# Start workflow popup menu is empty in OpenKM web interface

Tags: firefox, jboss, workflow, openkm

I've created a simple workflow in jBoss studio and deployed it on OpenKM, every things is OK and my workflow will be shown in administration panel but in desktop panel there is no files in `/okm:root/` and when I want to start my workflow the workflow lists in 'workflow start' dialog is empty, Did not have any entry.

Can any one please help me with how can I start my workflow?

As a note, I uses Firefox 30 and Java plug-in is disable on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enable available workflow list from profiles ( administration -> profiles -> first tab). Also to start any workflow you need to doing it selecting a document.

In addition if your problem is that you're not showing th form just when you start workflow then take in consideration, there's an special task name in forms.xml if you want to be shown the form at the moment you're registering. You can see example in this form with task called task="run_config":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE workflow-forms PUBLIC "-//OpenKM//DTD Workflow Forms 2.1//EN"
                                "http://www.openkm.com/dtd/workflow-forms-2.1.dtd">
<workflow-forms>
  <workflow-form task="run_config">
    <input label="number" name="number" />
    <button name="submit" label="Submit" />
  </workflow-form>
  <workflow-form task="task">
    <input label="number" name="number" data="modified" />
    <button name="submit" label="Submit" />
  </workflow-form>
</workflow-forms>
```

Here you can find some examples http://wiki.openkm.com/index.php/File:Course_workflows.zip, also I suggest take a look on it. Hope this could be useful for you

Comment: Did you read my question at all ? `:)` however thanks for your response

Comment: You must enable available workflow list from profiles ( administration -> profiles -> first tab). Also to start any workflow you need to doing it selecting a document.

Comment: By selecting my workflow in profile page, It worked!, Many thanks man, please update your answer with this notes, I'll accept it